# building a regex to detect dictionaries

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure this out for the life of me. Python 2.7.

I have a config file that is something like

```
define something {
    var    val1
    var    val2
}

define something_else {
    var    val3
    var    val4}
...
```

and I want to match each "object" starting from "define." What I want to do is basically delete one of these entire objects from a file if a sequence occurs inside of the object.

So far I have

`re.compile(r"(define.+\{\n)((.*\n)*)(\})")`

but this matches everything until the last index and wont match the `}` character.

I've also tried `re.compile(r"(define.+\{\n)((\s*\S*)*)(\})")` but that doesn't seem to work either. For some reason the regex grabs everything and won't catch the closing bracket at all.

I realize that a line with just a closing bracket could be either

`\n}` or `}` or `(some number of spaces) }` or `var valx (some number of spaces) }`

but I don't think that should matter.

Also the config files are pre-checked to make sure the var/val syntax is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the `+` qualifier to behave in a non-greedy way and go only to the first matching `}`:

```
re.findall(r'define [^{]+{[^}]+?}', data)
# ['define something {\n    var    val1\n    var    val2\n}', 
#  'define something_else {\n    var    val3\n    var    val4}']
```

Comment: ah, `Adding ? after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched`. Totally did not use that to my advantage. Also seeing how you minimized my matching expression helped. Thank you!